# Avoiding render warning in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am getting the following warning in my React Native app while I am verifying if my user is new or not.

`Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within`render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.`

Here is what I am trying to do

```
renderNewUser() {
        return (
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Welcome')
        )
    }

    render() {
        const { loadingVisible } = this.state;
        const { loading, error, me } = this.props.getMe;
        if (loading) {
            return (
                <Loader
                    modalVisible={loadingVisible}
                    animationType="fade"
                />
            )
        } else if (error) {
            return console.log
        } else {
            return (
                me.newUser ? this.renderNewUser() : <RenderListingsEmployer navigation={this.props.navigation} />
            )
        }
    }
```

Any idea how to escape from this?

Comment: Your `this.props.navigation.navigate('Welcome')` most likely trigger a `setState` which is not allowed when it is rendering. You might be able to use `componentDidUpdate` instead.

Comment: 2 things you could try: declare your const outside the render method and avoid using console.log (which is neither state nor props)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
class Foo extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.getMe.me.newUser) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Welcome');
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { loadingVisible } = this.state;
    const { loading, error, me } = this.props.getMe;

    return (
      {
        loading
          ? <Loader modalVisible={loadingVisible} animationType="fade" />
          : <RenderListingsEmployer navigation={this.props.navigation} />
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I agree that the problem might be on console.log usage

Comment: You also shouldn't be trying to navigate somewhere from inside of render. It's better to call that in the life cycle method imo. Leave render to handle presentation.

Comment: I was thinking to use it in a life cycle but somehow I need to wait for this.props.getMe.me.newUse to become available before navigating to 'Welcome' or stay on the screen

Comment: `componentDidMount` is called after the component has rendered. So `this.props.getMe.me.newUse` should be available.

Comment: it is available until this.props.getMe after this.props.getMe.loading become false this.props.getMe.me become available so I need to wait for this.props.getMe.loading to become false to call that